# SSIS package throws an error : out of memory Exception

Tags: out-of-memory, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I have design SSIS package in which i need to use more than 150 Merge join.I have divide whole package in 13 child packages.all 13 package runs individually fine .
but when i have create master package to call all the package it throws an error for out of memory.

I have set one property of data flow task [DefaultBufferMaxRows to 1000 from 10000] and set BLOBTempStoragePath for every package but it didn't works.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2008R2 the only way I know of to get around this was to create a "wrapper" package that insulates the parent from the child (call the wrapper and pass in the child package you want to call and the wrapper dynamically calls it). In that way SSDT doesn't attempt to cache the child packages until they are called. This enabled us to run well over 100 child packages.

I did not re-test this in 2012 but 2012 was supposed to handle memory better in this situation. If you're on 2012, then I suspect they didn't solve the problem.